# Data wrangling with Python Pandas and pivoting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, apply

I have a simple DataFrame containing population data for different years, regions, and countries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                           'two'],
                   'region': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'C'],
                   'population 2015': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 90],
                   'population 2016': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 900]})
```

I pivoted the DataFrame as follows, to transform it into a specific structure:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='region', columns='country', values=['population 2015', 'population 2016']).fillna(0)
df1
```

Now, I am struggling with calculating each regions total population for each year. I want to this in an efficient and generalizable way, e.g. without using loops. But maybe by using the .apply() and .sum() methods, or the use of of a lambda function.

The output should look similar to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'region': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   'population 2015': [10, 20, 120, 40, 50],
                   'population 2016': [100, 200, 1200, 400, 500]})
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  with [`level`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) with [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df1 = df1.sum(level=0, axis=1).reset_index()
print(df1)
```

**Output**:

```
  region  population 2015  population 2016
0      A             10.0            100.0
1      B             20.0            200.0
2      C            120.0           1200.0
3      D             40.0            400.0
4      E             50.0            500.0
```

**Matching the output format**:

```
df1 = df1.sum(level=0, axis=1).reset_index()
df1.iloc[:, 1:] = df1.iloc[:, 1:].astype(int)
print(df1)
```

```
  region  population 2015  population 2016
0      A               10              100
1      B               20              200
2      C              120             1200
3      D               40              400
4      E               50              500
```

Comment: added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does consider accepting/check-marking the answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It works very well! To calculate weights: How would I divide the pivoted DataFrame by the answer you provided, e.g.the two columns for 'population 2015' by the 'population 2015' column of your answer (and for 2016)? I think the .DataFrame.divide() method would work. Maybe everything can be done in one go? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, Glad it helps. The tradition is to accept and upvote if you have enough reputation. You were right!  Weights can be easily calculated with this `df1 = df1.div(df1.sum(axis=1, level=0), level=0)`. Happy Coding!